# I get an error message about not enough arguments to return

Tags: go

I want return string or slice at one function, I can use in php. 
but, get some error in Go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // arr := []int {34, 23, 45, 56, 62, 45, 12, 96, 22}
    arr := []int{}

    fmt.Println(test(arr))
}

func test(dataList []int ) ( string ,  []int )  {
    if dataList == nil{
       return "this is string"
    }

    return []int{}
}
```

error: not enough arguments to return

Comment: You defined the `test` function as returning two values, one `string` and the other `[]int`, that means you have to return two values, not one or the other, but both. Use `return "this is string", nil` and `return "", []int{}`. Go does not support "optional" returns.

Comment: yes, i understand , tks

Comment: If you take a few minutes to take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) this type of basic syntax question will be answered for you.

Comment: tks, i am not careful enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define two return types, you always need to return the two types. You can not return only one.

Have a look at this:

```
func test(dataList []int) (string, []int) {
    if dataList == nil {
        return "this is string", []int{}
    }

    return "", []int{}
}
```

This would work, because I am returning both a `string` and an `[]int` in every case (and in exact the defined order).

Maybe if you can explain what your function tries to accomplish, we can give better advice on how to design the function.

Comment: nothing goal in fact, i just want to know is it feasible, tks very much